# UISplitViewController: Navigating within detailView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with a SplitView that lets you add companies to a database.
In the masterView the companies are shown with their respective company names.
Tapping on one of these companies shows me the address in a "viewCell" (not actually a cell just a view within a viewController, just easier to explain).
Below that "viewCell" is a tableView (still in the same viewController) with one row: "Employees". Tapping on that leads me to a new tableViewController that lists all the employees that I can add or that I added.

I would like to use a navBarItem to go back and forth between the CompanyDetailViewController and the EmployeesTableViewController.

On iPhone this works nicely with a transition with the automatically created "< Back" navBarItem.
On iPad this does not work. It does not show any navBarItem. I know the reason (the `EmployeeTableViewController` "thinks" it's the detailView of the masterView, hence it does not need one), but I'd like to be able to transition back and worth with an animation.

My `prepareForSegue` from the `CompanyDetailView` to `EmployeesTableViewController` looks like this:

```
if (segue.identifier == "ShowEmployeesSegue")
{
    let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! EmployeesTableViewController
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

    controller.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
    controller.companyToView = companyToView as? Company
}
```

**Update: Some Screenshots**

- iPhone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivl86.png

  1. MasterView with 3 Test Companies
  2. DetailView of Test Company 1
  3. List of employees of Test Company 1 after tapping on Employees, "< Back"-Button visible
- iPad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObBto.png

  1. MasterView with DetailView of Test Company 1
  2. List of Employees of Test Company 1, **No "< Back"-Button visible to go back to DetailView of Test Company 1**

Comment: Question is little bit unlcear. Can you show few screens, like a what are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some understanding, the following could be your solution.

Check in the code, if the action for it is showDetailViewController:sender.

Open the select Storyboard -> Open as Source Code.
Find your object  (might be by x and y).

The working connection segue should like the below

```
<connections>
               <segue destination="UXJ-Si-1aa" kind="show" id="aDD-wp-6dZ"/>

</connections>
```

Delete the action if you might have and try again, in the following  way.
Select the button, `cntrl` + drag the pointer to your ViewController. Shown in images

If you have segue like the below **one would not work** , and **will not show UINavigationBar**

```
    <connections> 
    <segue destination="UXJ-Si-1aa" kind="show" action="showDetailViewController:sender:" id="A8L-Ad-PKT"/> 

</connections>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion (even though I didn't know what it is supposed to change :P ), but to no avail.

Comment: Can you print self.navigationController in the controller which is not showing Back Button?

Comment: `Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7fba09065600>)`

Comment: I posted the correct answer. It works now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That's why you get the correct answer as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what caused it. I embedded the employeeViewController in a NavigationController. I connected it directly and now it works. I simply needed to change the prepareForSegue-method like so:

```
if (segue.identifier == "ShowEmployeesSegue") {
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! EmployeesTableViewController
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

controller.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
controller.companyToView = companyToView as? Company }
```